# what permission to apply for access to Radio information in blackberry

Tags: permissions, blackberry

When I install my app, a dialog pops up that asks for user permission to access Radio information. I added ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_DATA but it still pops up the same dialog. I then used ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_LOCATION_API but the result is still the same. How can I prevent the dialog from poping up? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how platform works. It should at least ask user once about app permissions. Depends if user saves his choice it won't ask anymore.

It's quite similar to android where user have to give permission to te application during installation.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I want to ask the user only once, so that the user can save the permission. But It still  pops up the dialog window.

Comment: It means that user didn't save his choice. If you didn't specify permission app should fail with exception even without asking

Comment: Can you tell me what permission should I set to get this working?